# How do I combine pseudo-elements with pseudo-classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

How do I combine pseudo-elements like `:after` with pseudo-classes like `:hover` and `:not`?

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
li:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #009688;
  transition: width .8s;
}
li:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>forth</li>
  <li>fifth</li>
</ul>
```

How can I exclude, for example, the first and third items in the list from this hover effect?

Comment: Just combine as usual...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class with `:nth-child()` selector like this.

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
li:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #009688;
  transition: width .8s;
}
li:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(3)):hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>forth</li>
  <li>fifth</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 12):

There are no special rules around combining pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements, besides the one rule that says [there can only be one pseudo-element per complex selector and it must appear at the very end](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax). Pseudo-classes can be written in any order — the order of simple selectors doesn't change the meaning of a compound selector. Note that a pseudo-element, unlike a pseudo-class, is not a simple selector.

You can write any of

```
li:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(3)):hover:after
```

or

```
li:hover:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(3)):after
```

or

```
li:hover:not(:nth-child(3)):not(:nth-child(1)):after
```

or, heck, even

```
li:not(:nth-child(3)):hover:not(:nth-child(1)):after
```

and you would get the same result (assuming the browser isn't buggy), as long as `:after`, the pseudo-element, appears last (and `li`, the type selector, appears first).

By convention, most authors choose to place structural pseudo-classes, such as `:nth-child()`, before dynamic pseudo-classes, such as `:hover`. But this is entirely personal preference; it doesn't matter to the browser.